# Compare lists in different dictionaries and match similarities

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compatibility

I would like to compare lists belonging to different dictionaries and print if there are any similarities

```
dictionary = { 'C1' : [10,20,30], 'C2' : [20,30,40]}
dictionarya = { 'S1' : [10,21,31], 'S2' : [22,32,42]}

print ('You have...')
for f, v in zip(dictionary, dictionarya):
    for x, y in zip(f, v):
        if x == y:
            print (x)
            break
else:
      print ('no similarities')
```

i expect to match the 10 of C1 to the 10 of S1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this generator expression with a nested iteration with two `zip`s and a `if` statement and a `next`:

```
print(next((str(a) + ', ' + str(x[0]) + ', ' + str(y[0]) for x, y in zip(dictionary.items(), dictionarya.items()) for a, b in zip(x[1], y[1]) if a == b), 'no similarities'))
```

Output:

```
10, C1, S1
```

But if there isn't any matches, since I have `next`, it will output:

```
no similarities
```

Comment: It would be much, much more readable without list comprehension

Comment: @ksbg Well, it's easier this way

Comment: thank you for the help. is it possible to add the source of the output. meaning where the 10 is from.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what U9-Forward's code shows: the issue is that when you zip() the 2 dictionaries, what is zipped are the dict keys.  You are after the values.

Also, the `else:` will always run, so you need some kind of flag to track if you ever found any matching values.